# Prevent Ditto from copying in KeePass

Tags: windows, ditto

There is an option in [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net) that says

```
Accepted copy application (separate by ;)
Include [*  ]     Exclude [   ]
```

How does the exclude list work? I guessed that it matches the name of the application window and tried inputting `KeePass`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: *Ditto* as in `ditto(1)`, the command line tool that comes with Mac OS X?

Comment: No, that should be obvious from the question. Ditto is a clipboard manager for Windows. Did it tag it wrong?

Comment: Since KeePass is available for Windows and via Mono for OS X, BSD, Linux,... you forgot to mention *Windows*. No big deal, edited it a bit for you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try "KeePass.exe", it's working fine for me.

Comment: +1 Same goes for lastpass: `lastapp_x64.exe` (I guess the 32-bit version will have `64` replaced with `32`)

Answer (score 13):

Put "KeePass.exe" under Ditto/Options/General/Exclude:

[image: Ditto Screenshot with KeePass.exe excluded]

Comment: A bit outdated screenshot, but still the same path, though.